# Make link that makes page translate into another language?

Tags: multilingual, translate

I'm trying to make buttons for my website that, when clicked, translates the content of the page (and if possible, the entire website) into another language. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do this?

I'm not quite sure how to start, or even what language do use. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Try using [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en)

Comment: This is sort of what I want, but I want to be able to control the image of the link clicked (in this case a flag of the country of the language to translate to) and then have that be the language translated to upon clicking.

Comment: you will have to test if this is possible with Google